# Cannot resolve symbol 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'

Tags: android

I made an empty activity in Android Studio, ahead of nothing added, in activity_main.xml, there were so many red lines,and the prompt was:
Cannot resolve symbol'[image: Cannot resolve symbol'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout']'

while, these code was generated by Android Studio, I tried file->invalidate cashes/restart... and installed all the SDK tools but Google series. The error was still there.

Has anyone a solution ?